# dir-pagination directive angularjs : is there any way I can get all the records of current page in pagination?

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat, dirpagination

I am using dir-pagination directive by @michaelbromley. I want to get all the records on the current page of directive. Is there any way to do this?

[image: dir-paginate pic]

Here is the link: [dir-pagination](http://plnkr.co/edit/gJbMTzWQX0g5ClKcINqJ?p=preview), so I need a collection of 5 `records` from 100 to 96. Is there any quick way to do it?

I have tried couple of things but not working.

Comment: plnkr 
    http://plnkr.co/edit/gJbMTzWQX0g5ClKcINqJ?p=preview

Comment: try this : http://plnkr.co/edit/7OfKd7xbRHkzFIPlpWS7?p=preview

Comment: Do you want to get these 5 records on button click?

Comment: Yes! If that's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another possible way to do it, which does not require you to duplicate the logic from the `dir-paginate` expression:

For each repeated item, you could just push that item into an array in your controller. This will of course give you all the items for that page.

Here is an example:

```
<ul>
   <li dir-paginate="meal in perman  = ( meals | filter:q ) | orderBy: order?'key':'-key' | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage" ng-init="addMeal(meal)">{{ meal.key + ': ' +meal.val }}</li>
</ul>
```

Then in the controller:

```
$scope.addMeal = function(meal) {
  if (meal) {
    if ($scope.page.length === $scope.pageSize + 1) {
      $scope.page = [];
    }
    $scope.page.push(meal);
  }
}
```

I've not expensively tested it, but the general principle should work. It's a bit hacky in my opinion, but it's worth knowing as an alternative to the answer provided by Rathish.

Comment: Thanks Michael for reply. Is there any way I can get the current page index in my controller. means on which page I am currently.

Comment: When using a filter query, and typing and backspacing repeatedly, it is possible to trick this into losing track of the current page. It isn't useful when using dir-paginate and filtering at the same time. In my case, if I repeatedly typed and deleted `u`, the page would get out of sync.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue, but the answers here didn't fulfill my needs (or maybe wants). I decided to solve it myself, and settled on creating a filter whose sole purpose is to record the items passing through it in a given property on a given target. I came up with this:

```
/**
 * Author: Eric Ferreira <http://stackoverflow.com/users/2954747/eric-ferreira> ©2015
 *
 * This filter will sit in the filter sequence, and its sole purpose is to record 
 * the current contents to the given property on the target object. It is sort of
 * like the 'tee' command in *nix cli.
 */
angular.module('app').filter('record', function() {
    return function(array, property, target) {
        if (target && property) {
            target[property] = array;
        }
        return array;
    }
});
```

Then you use the filter in your pagination (or anywhere you want to get the current array actually [think, after filtering with a search query, after paging, after filtering current page, et cetera]) like so:

```
<div dir-paginate="item in items | itemsPerPage:pageSize | record:'currentPage':this">{{item.text}}</div>
```

You can also use it multiple times in one sequence:

```
<div dir-paginate="item in items | filter:searchQuery | record:'filtered':this | itemsPerPage:pageSize | record:'currentPage':this">{{item.text}}</div>
```

The above would record both the current page and all records resulted from the current filter query.

This will record (and update whenever it changes) the current page in `$scope.currentPage`. The `this` in the above example is the target of the filter. It resolves to `$scope.this` which, for most intents and purposes, is just `$scope`.

In your specific case, you would use this line (after adding/requiring the filter in your module) instead for your pagination:

```
<li dir-paginate="meal in perman  = ( meals | filter:q ) | orderBy: order?'key':'-key' | itemsPerPage: pageSize | record:'currentPage':this">{{ meal.key + ': ' +meal.val }}</li>
```

I went ahead and forked your plunker to show it working too:

http://plnkr.co/edit/uC3RiC?p=preview

Comment: How would this record if an item is not allowed through the filter? Is `target` somehow being reset?

Comment: This only saves the items that reach it, so it wouldn’t save anything filtered out by a previous filter. If you want to save the list before a given filter, just put this before the other filter in the list of filters.

Comment: actually what I was referring to was the fact that the filters will frequently process. Just looking at the code I would think that when the filters restart, and find less results that the previous execution that it would not remove the missing results so you would end up with more than you think are visible.

Comment: Well it doesn’t record incrementally; it wipes out the previous reference each time it is called. So it wouldn’t ever get out of synchronization with the actual values.

Comment: That's a great idea @EricF !

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can create our own logic according to data.

```
Displaying {{ pageSize * (currentPage-1)+$index+1 }} - {{ pageSize*currentPage }} of {{ perman.length }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use array slice method since you already have access to the large array, know which page number you are on and know the number of elements per page. You can reuse the getPage function in the below code to achieve this.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.pageSize = 5;
  var meals = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

  function getPage(currentPage, pageSize, arr, reverse) {  
    var beginIndex, endIndex, noOfPages;

    if(reverse) {
       beginIndex = arr.length - currentPage * pageSize;  
    } else {
      beginIndex = currentPage * pageSize - pageSize;
    }

    endIndex = beginIndex + pageSize;
    beginIndex = beginIndex < 0 ? 0 : beginIndex;
    return arr.slice(beginIndex, endIndex);
  }

  //This will return the 5 elements in page 1 of meals array which will be meals 11 to 15 since the array is bound to the pagination directive in the reverse (desc) order
  $scope.firstFiveArrRev = getPage($scope.currentPage, $scope.pageSize, meals, true);

  //This will return the 5 elements in page 1 of meals array which will be meals 1 to 5 since the array is bound to the pagination directive in ascending order
  $scope.firstFiveArr = getPage($scope.currentPage, $scope.pageSize, meals, false);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.0"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Displaying elements from page number {{currentPage}}
    <br />
    Page size is set to {{pageSize}}
    <br />
    When order is Reverse: true
    <div>{{ firstFiveArrRev.toString() }}</div>

    When order is Reverse: false
    <div>{{ firstFiveArr.toString() }}</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Here is the plnkr**

http://plnkr.co/edit/CgH1WFR1JvOLmQsacVoI?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the solution I also had same thing but I want to know if there are any straight forward way to get current page records in dir-pagination directive.

Comment: This gets annoying when also using a filter

Answer (score -1):

1. Download [dirPagination.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js) from here.
2. Now include *dirPagination.js* to your page.
3. Add *angularUtils.directives.dirPagination* in your module like this

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

4. We use `dir-paginate` directive for pagination ,add `dir-paginate` in `tr` tag

```html
<tr dir-paginate="event in events|orderBy:['columnid', 't']:true | itemsPerPage: 5">
```

5. Add below given code anywhere on your page or where ever you want.

```html
<dir-pagination-controls
                max-size="5"
                direction-links="true"
                boundary-links="true" >
</dir-pagination-controls>
```